# Where does a list item go when it is deleted using Server Object Model?

Tags: splistitem, splist, splistitemcollection, recycle-bin

Assumptions: I have a custom SharePoint list with 2 items in it.

In one case i delete one item from the list manually and check the recycle bin,here i find the deleted item.

Now in the second case i delete the second item using server object model,following is the code

```
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
     lstBookings.Items.DeleteItemById(bk_item.ID);
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

But this time when i check the recycle bin i cannot find the deleted item, so my question is **Where does an item go if it is deleted via server object model?**

Thanks...

Comment: You should post new questions as new questions, and not update your question so radically after people have answered it

Answer (score 2):

There are two options in sharepoint to delete the listitem:

1. `listitem.Recycle()` deletes the list item and puts it in the recycle bin
2. `listitem.Delete()` deletes the item permanently

If you delete a document in SharePoint using the User Interface, it’s being moved to the Recycle Bin, so that it can be restored if necessary. Calling the SPListItem.Delete() method. While this does the job, and deletes the item, it deletes it permanently instead of moving to the Recycle Bin. SPListItem.Recycle() method moves a list item/document to the Recycle Bin instead of deleting it permanently.

Comment: when we put an item in recycle bin, where is it actually stored, is it in the content_db? And how much memory does it occupy? And can we query the item which is in the recycle bin?

Comment: Most Probably yes, By default all are in content DB. I don.t have any msdn article for this.